# Iterator ignored by ddply function

Tags: r, scope, iterator, plyr

In a data.frame , I'm trying to determine various quantiles of some column summarized by another column. For example, assume I want various quantiles of `iris$Petal.Length` for each `iris$Species`.

The number and values of the quantiles is dynamic, so ultimately I'd trying to either loop through the probabilities or somehow vectorize it. Here's my vectorized attempt which doesn't quite work.

```
rm(list = ls())

require(plyr)

myDat <- iris

myProbs <- c(0, 0.15, 0.5, 1)

# This doesn't return the DF I'm looking for (where probabilities/names are identified)
petals_by_species <- ddply(myDat, "Species", summarize, Quantiles = quantile(Petal.Length, probs = myProbs))
petals_by_species
```

The above returns the correct data, but not in an elegant format. The output appears like:

[image]

The values above are correct, but it's not intuitive how to convert to wide format, nor is it explicit what the probabilities are.

I try some hacky work-around to merge results into some wide format like so:

```
rm(list = ls())

require(plyr)

myDat <- iris

myProbs <- c(0, 0.15, 0.5, 1)

# So, I loop through the probabilities and combine.
for(i in 1:length(myProbs)){

  temp <- ddply(myDat, "Species", summarize, Quantiles = quantile(Petal.Length, probs = myProbs[i]))

  names(temp) <- c("Species", paste0("Prob ", myProbs[i]))

  if(i == 1){
    petals_by_species <- temp
  } else {
    petals_by_species <- merge(petals_by_species, temp)
  }
}

petals_by_species
```

This output is thoroughly confusing... the column names are correct, but the values are incorrect (each column appears repeated).

[image]

None of the above columns return the correct value.

Clearly I'm not going about this the correct way. But now my curiosity is piqued, **why do the below lines of code return different values?**

```
require(plyr)

myDat <- iris

myProbs <- c(0, 0.15, 0.5, 1)

intendedOutput <- ddply(myDat, "Species", summarize, Quantiles = quantile(Petal.Length, probs = myProbs[1]))
intendedOutput

i = 1
unintendedOutput <- ddply(myDat, "Species", summarize, Quantiles = quantile(Petal.Length, probs = myProbs[i]))
unintendedOutput
```

[image]

How do I get `ddply` to recognize my iterator the way I'm expecting? Is there a different `plyr` function I should be using? I've tried `daply` without success.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the ticket, from a separate correspondence with Hadley:

```
rm(list = ls())

require(plyr)

myDat <- iris

myProbs <- c(0, 0.15, 0.5, 1)

# This doesn't return the DF I'm looking for (where probabilities/names are identified)
petals_by_species <- ddply(myDat, "Species", summarize, Quantiles = quantile(Petal.Length, probs = myProbs), probs = myProbs)
petals_by_species
```

Then my output is in long format, with the inputs reported, like so:

[image]